# Как сделать фиксированное боковое меню?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно сделать аналогичное меню, по функционалу.
Что бы при скролле основной раздел раскрылся и показал на каком подразделе вы находитесь, и так же при переходе на следующий что бы предыдущий закрылся.

вот пример [ссылка на пример](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так же фиксированным. в каком направлении мне искать ответ на мой вопрос.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window#window-scroll

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/846948/33274  я здесь две панели зразу зафиксировал

Comment: Как понимать ваше «надо»? Может, сразу на фриланс тогда? Где ваш пример кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В примере скорее всего использован компонент ScrollSpy из Bootstrap. Вот [посмотрите](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#scrollspy) - на сайте бутстрапа он тоже использован, в примере даже внешний вид очень похож.